# I am having trouble in getting response from the php webservice stored on my web server

Tags: php, web-services

This is the php web service stored on my web server

```
<?php

    if ($_POST){
        echo json_encode($_POST);
    };
?>
```

If i use this on localhost, it works fine.
like this

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $("#send").click(function(){

        var form = $("#form").serialize();
        console.log(form);
         $.post("http://localhost/test/index.php",form,function(response){
           alert(response);
        })
     });

  </script>
```

But If i try this with my webservice url, it doesn't work.
Here is the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $("#send").click(function(){

        var form = $("#form").serialize();
        console.log(form);
         $.post("http://aonebasket.in/test_app/index.php",form,function(response){
           alert(response);
        })
     });

  </script>
```

Please help

Comment: Check the browser console. I suspect you are trying to access your Ajax URL hosted on aonebasket from localhost - ie, the script is being run from localhost but is trying to make an Ajax request to a remote host. This will not work as it becomes an XSS request and most modern browsers won't allow it.

Comment: Ensure your Ajax request script -- 
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $("#send").click(function(){

        var form = $("#form").serialize();
        console.log(form);
         $.post("http://localhost/test/index.php",form,function(response){
           alert(response);
        })
     });

  </script>
resides in a file hosted on aonebasket.in